# How to identify text position in docx file?

Tags: python, openxml, docx, python-docx

I am new to Docx extraction and I am trying to identify headings and paragraphs in a page. Although I was able to retrieve the font information from runs, paragraphs and styles.xml, I couldn't find text positioning information exactly or maybe I am not searching in the right place

I went through python-docx object and saw `paragraph_format` object which has `alignment`, `left_indent` etc... but many paragraphs have these values as None, which according to documentation says these are inherited.

[image: paragraph_format object]

My expectation is to have some numeric values for each paragraph which describes their start and end positions from left and right. Which should be left-indent and right-indent if am not wrong.

Where can I find these values if they are not present in python-docx paragraph object and which xml files will contain this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherited values for paragraph position will be the page margins. A paragraph with no left or right indent extends from one page margin to the other and any indents are relative to those margins.

(Page) margins are attributes of each section and may change from one section to another (although they typically don't).
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#id1

Comment: is there any way to identify whether a paragraph belongs to a section?